# How to configure AutoHotKey for Win-Tab instead of Alt-Tab

Tags: autohotkey

AutoHotKey is excellent keyboard customisation and automation utility. I have configured it for Alt-Tab using my mouse:

```
~MButton & WheelDown::AltTab
~MButton & WheelUp::ShiftAltTab
```

I am using Windows Vista and instead of using Alt-Tab, I would like to configure the mouse buttons for Win-Tab (Flip-3D). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the middle button should activate Flip 3D, then scrolling up or down will move the windows accordingly. The problem is that keeping MButton and MWheel up or down mapped to open Flip 3D will cause problems, as every scroll will attempt to relaunch the application (and probably close it) so I removed the MButton part.

```
~MButton::send ^#{Tab}
WheelDown::send { down 1 }
WheelUp::send { up 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gives compilation error but it works when I needed to write send in all lines (just like first one). Please can you fix this so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: changed it a bit tell me if it works

Comment: wooo...It compiles well but it when I wheel-down after clicking middle mouse button, it keeps on rotating instead of flipping just one window.

Comment: whoops, sorry about that haha. Give it a try now.