# How to reassign a Windows shortcut key?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reassigning the AltGr key to the Windows Key in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/19526/reassigning-the-altgr-key-to-the-windows-key-in-windows-7)

I find the Windows+Tab key combination a bit uncomfortable on the fingers. How can I reassign this to something else?

Platform: Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

You may like a solution I came up with in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/44404/how-to-configure-autohotkey-for-win-tab-instead-of-alt-tab), which involves using the middle mouse button to activate the Flip-3D then using the wheel to go back and forth. This involves [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

You could also completely remap a key you don't use often (such as caps lock) to a Windows key using [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/):

[image]

It depends on which keys are most comfortable for you.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit a duplicate but take a look at this thread:

[Reassigning the AltGr key to the Windows Key in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/19526/reassigning-the-altgr-key-to-the-windows-key-in-windows-7)

It's working for Vista also!

> [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 7 / XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)